# python WSDL.Proxy behind a http proxy

Tags: python, wsdl, http-proxy, soappy

I have a simple code that works when I'm not behind any proxy but doesn't work when I am behind a proxy. So is there any way I can specify that the connection has to be made through the `http_proxy` in the constructor of `WSDL.Proxy` class? I have been trying out [ideone.py](https://github.com/mkilling/ideone.py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to apply the following patch to `ideone.py`:

```
diff --git a/ideone.py b/ideone.py
index fffdf27..b15abef 100644
--- a/ideone.py
+++ b/ideone.py
@@ -42,10 +42,10 @@ def getError(response):


 class IdeOne:
-    def __init__(self, user='test', password='test'):
+    def __init__(self, user='test', password='test', **kwargs):
         self._user = user
         self._password = password
-        self._wsdlObject = WSDL.Proxy('http://ideone.com/api/1/service.wsdl')
+        self._wsdlObject = WSDL.Proxy('http://ideone.com/api/1/service.wsdl', **kwargs)

     def testFunction(self):
         response = self._wsdlObject.testFunction(self._user, self._password)
```

This will allow passing keyword arguments to the `WSDL.Proxy` which will be used to create its internal [`Client.SOAPProxy`](https://github.com/kiorky/SOAPpy/blob/develop/src/SOAPpy/Client.py#L339) instance. [`Client.SOAPProxy`](https://github.com/kiorky/SOAPpy/blob/develop/src/SOAPpy/Client.py#L339) has a `http_proxy` keyword argument, so then, after the patch applied, `IdeOne(user='test', password='test', http_proxy='the.http.proxy')` should work.